# Is it special to Chess Stack Exchange that we can show static pictures of a board?

Tags: support, pgn-viewer

I saw this question:

[Can a piece pinned to my king put the opponent's king in check?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/2348/11939)

which has a chess board inserted with the `[fen]` tag. Is this special to Chess Stack Exchange?

Comment: There was a question about the PGN viewer on [Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272714/340816) and it was closed because it was specific to Chess SE.

Comment: @Christophe that does not help me, there was never an answer.

Comment: Did you read the close reason for that question? It says, "This question pertains only to a specific site in the Stack Exchange Network. (...)". Doesn't that implicitly answer your question?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe why would that answer my question?

Comment: It implies that the PGN viewer was only implemented on Chess SE. Even 
Board & Card Games SE doesn't have one. See [How should I concisely represent a chess position in a question?](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/496) and [Please implement the Chess replayer on Board and Card Games](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/978).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Chess SE is the only Stack Exchange site where the PGN/FEN renderer was implemented:

- In January 2016, someone asked a [question about the PGN viewer on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272714/340816), which was closed as off-topic. The argument for closing it was, "This question pertains only to a specific site in the Stack Exchange Network. Questions on Meta Stack Exchange should pertain to our network or software that drives it as a whole, (...)."
- Outside Chess SE, Board & Card Games SE would be the site where this renderer would be most relevant. The meta site has several questions about it:

  - [Can we integrate software to show Go and Chess positions?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/425/19473) is a question from April 2011 (apparently during the beta phase) that asks for this feature, and none of the answers state that it got implemented.
  - [How should I concisely represent a chess position in a question?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/495/19473) is a question from June 2011 where the first answer says that the site is unlikely to get an FEN renderer.
  - [Please implement the Chess replayer on Board and Card Games](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/978/19473) is another request for this feature, this time from January 2013. Again, nothing in the comments or answers suggests that it got implemented.
  - I asked in the Board & Card Games chat whether it got implemented, and the response (from one of the site's moderators) was not positive.